# Is there a logic error in the LET variables definition type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax, let

- There is a code between the 1st log and the 2nd log. I assign the `validate` variable to the `s` variable using the `let` definition type.

```
console.log(validate); // 1. log

let s = validate;
if (s.location != null)
   delete s['location'];

console.log(validate.location); // 2. log
```

In this case, the screen output looks like this:

```
{ // 1
  min_price: 2,
  max_price: 5,
  location: { latitude: 234.2244555, longitude: 245.33333 }
}
undefined // 2
```

Isn't it very strange? Because after I do `let s = validate;` I do `delete s['location];` but after this operation when I do `console.log(validate.location);` I get `undefined`.

- So I wrote the following instead of `let s = validate;` on the code and the result was fine:

```
let s = {
  ...validate
};
```

In this case, when we take the screen output again, the output is fixed as follows:

```
{ // 1
  min_price: 2,
  max_price: 5,
  location: { latitude: 234.2244555, longitude: 245.33333 }
}
{ location: { latitude: 234.2244555, longitude: 245.33333 } } // 2
```

Now my question is, is the difference between `let s = validate;` and `let s = { ...validate };` because of the `let` definition type? Because I couldn't find a logical explanation for this conflict.

Comment: Has nothing to do with `let`. When you do `s = validate` you're assigning a reference to `validate` to `s`. With the spread, you're making a shallow copy.

Comment: *"Isn't it very strange?"* - Not at all.  In that first example, both `s` and `validate` are references to the same object.  Assigning an object reference to a new variable doesn't create a copy/clone of that object.